# How to run unit test only in Fastlane

Tags: ios, fastlane

Is there a way to run unit tests only?

Currently, `run_test`(https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/run_tests/) will trigger both UI and unit test

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a separate XCode scheme for UI and Unit tests? If it's so, you can specify a scheme to run which contains only UI/Unit tests:

```
run_tests(
  workspace: "App.xcworkspace",
  scheme: "MyAppUITests"
)
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't think this will work since I can see here something like "The scheme 'XXXX' has nothing configured to build for Running and has no executable specified to Run. Edit the scheme to configure the Run action.
[21:41:29]: Exit status: 70"

Comment: Could you check screens I've just attached please? From the error description, it seems like you should just specify Executable field with your .app file

Answer (score 1):

I can make it with UI testing schema. However, I still fails on unit test scheme. i can see this kind of error in fastlane

```
  lane :testsunit do
    run_tests(
      scheme: "XXX_Dev_UnitTests",
      # devices: ["iPhone 7", "iPhone 12"],
      )
  end
```

`The scheme 'XXXX_Dev_UnitTests' has nothing configured to build for Running and has no executable specified to Run. Edit the scheme to configure the Run action. [10:04:50]: Exit status: 70`

[image]

Comment: @Evgenii Shishko
can you help me look at it? Thanks

Comment: i tried the command of  "xcodebuild \
  -project cicd.xcodeproj \
  -scheme cicd \
  -sdk iphonesimulator \
  -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 12' \
  test \
  clean". it's not working too, same issue